# which sentence fits this definition of “when”?

Tags: conjunctions, definition

The Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English has the following definition of "when":

> used to introduce a fact or statement that makes something seem surprising

I'd like to know which of the following sentences better fits the definition:

> a. Why does she steal things when she could easily afford to buy them?

> b. When you consider that the airline handled 80 million passengers last year, the accident figures are really very small.

Does the fact that the airline handled 80 million passengers last year make the accident figures surprising or unsurprising in sentence b?

Comment: Both a. and b. are 100% correct usage of "when"

Comment: @TylerM Yes, but I'm asking which fits the quoted definition.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either of them fits the definition 'better'. Both of them fit it. If you're asking something else, it would be better to just tell us.

Comment: Does the fact that the airline handled 80 million passengers last year make the accident figures surprising or unsurprising in sentence b?

Comment: Well, let's say more surprising. It can be a problem when some article reports that there are X number of airplane accidents and Y number of car accidents. Without knowing the relative sizes of the populations, those figures aren't very comparable. The sentence is pointing out that the number of accidents is more acceptable given the number of passengers.

Comment: The mention of "surprising" should be replaced with something else in the definition, as it'd incorrectly rule out "His success isn’t surprising when you consider his background. "

Comment: I don't see any reason why you cannot negate the surprising part and still keep the grammatical structure.

Comment: The definition says, "_used to introduce a fact or statement that makes something seem surprising_." What is the "something" that's being matched to "_His success isn’t surprising when you consider his background_"?  Doesn't it seem odd to say "_It is surprising that his success isn't surprising_"?

Comment: You need to look up the word "pedant". I'm done.

Comment: Being precise is not equal to being a pedant, I'm afraid.

Comment: Consider this dialogue: _John: Did you know Tim can speak three languages fluently?
Sam: Wow, that's impressive. (Showing Sam's surprise at Tim's achievement)
John: Well, when you consider that he was born in an upper-class family and he has received private lessons two hours a day, five days a week, for over 20 years, his success isn't so surprising._

Comment: This example shows, contrary to what the definition says, "when (you conisder)" is used to show the extent, volume, quantity, etc., of something is not so great or so small as one might initially believe.